# JS accordion function

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with my function console.log return 3xexample after click and class open doesn't add. Could you please look at my code?

```
const accordionFunction = () => {
  const accordionProduct = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.cost-accordion__content-box ',
  );
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
  accordionProduct.forEach((element) => {
    const accordionLabel = element.parentElement.querySelector(
      '.cost-accordion__label',
    );
    const accordionContent = element.parentElement.querySelector(
      '.cost-accordion__content',
    );
    accordionLabel.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('example');
      accordionLabel.classList.toggle('active');
      accordionContent.classList.toggle('active');
    });
  });
```

};

```
<div class="cost-accordion"
  <div class="cost-accordion__content-box">
    <div class="cost-accordion__label cost-accordion__subtitle">abc</div>
    <div class="cost-accordion__content cost-accordion__description"> bcd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cost-accordion__content-box">
    <div class="cost-accordion__label cost-accordion__subtitle">abc</div>
    <div class="cost-accordion__content cost-accordion__description"> bcd</div>
  </div>
  <div class="cost-accordion__content-box">
    <div class="cost-accordion__label cost-accordion__subtitle">abc</div>
    <div class="cost-accordion__content cost-accordion__description"> bcd</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need `parentElement`...you don't need to look in the parent element to get your label and content, as they are direct children of your container:

```js
const accordionLabel = element.querySelector(
  '.cost-accordion__label',
);
const accordionContent = element.querySelector(
  '.cost-accordion__content',
);
```

One way to debug this is to log the element and see if the expected element shows up in the console:

```js
accordionProduct.forEach((element) => {
  accordionLabel.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log('element', element);
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it works. My js function now:

```
const accordionFunction = () => {
  const accordionProduct = document.querySelectorAll(
    '.cost-accordion__content-box ',
  );
  accordionProduct.forEach((element) => {
    const accordionLabel = element.querySelector('.cost-accordion__label');
    const accordionContent = element.querySelector('.cost-accordion__content');
    accordionLabel.addEventListener('click', () => {
      accordionLabel.classList.toggle('open');
      accordionContent.classList.toggle('open');
    });
  });
};
```